# Specifying the GPU ID using tensorflow backend

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu

I am trying to train the two different models using GPU ID.
I have tried the command `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1 python filename.py` but it picks up the GPU `0` rather than `1`.
I also added the os environment variable in my code, but I got the same behavior.
I am not sure how can I fix this as this is first time to use GPU.

Comment: Are you sure they are using GPU 0? The numbering inside TensorFlow might be different. What is the output of `nvidia-smi` command?

Comment: Actually someone was already using the `GPU 0`. And I didn't need to use `nvidia-smi` as I was getting memory error saying and it was displaying different chunks, limits etc. since `0` was already in use.

Comment: Question has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).